# Не находит встроенный класс ZipArchive в PHP

Tags: php, php.ini

У меня есть код:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

Выводит ошибку:
$zip = new ZipArchive();
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия PHP: 8.2.0
На седьмой версии PHP этот класс работал нормально. Теперь нет...
Что я пробовал:

1. я устанавливал php_zip.dll в папку ext
2. после этого прописывал в php.ini строку: extension=php_zip.dll
3. после этого перезагружал и Apache, и сам ПК, но всё равно не заработало

Уже почти неделю не могу решить эту проблему. Обыскал весь интернет, но везде показывают способы, которые я уже пробовал. В phpinfo() вообще не показывается раздел Zip. Буду очень благодарен, если сможете помочь

Comment: Если в phpinfo ничего не показывает, значит не включили... Это может быть например потому что dll не туда кинули, не в ту папку или неправильный ini файл правите. Или и то и то.

Comment: вы этот zip.dll нужной разрядности и ts/nts ставили?  Если в инфо не выводится, значит модуль не загружен. В логах запуска апача это должно быть отражено. Не загружен скорее всего по причине несовпадения разрядности, либо несовместимости версии пхп

Comment: Странно. Скачивал, вроде подходящую версию. Сейчас снова перекачаю. Мало ли